# Completely Uninstall TeamSpeak 3 Client

Tags: voip

I have installed TeamSpeak 3 using the .run file provided on their downloads page, but something has gone awfully wrong and I want to completely reset all settings to default. I figured that a clean reinstall would sort that out, but after removing the folder it unpacks and re-running their .run script, my settings remain in place.

Is there any way to completely remove TeamSpeak 3 so I can reinstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User's config file are normally stored in his own home directory but they may be hidden
try Showing hidden Files

```
View > Show Hidden Files
```

in Nautilus from your home directory it will show some '.' prefixed folders may be there will be a folder for this app too try removing it

```
ls -a
```

also help to show hidden files from terminal

Comment: Ctrl + H is the shortcut for hide/show hidden files